# Interpreting a Generalized Makefile

Tags: makefile

I came across this code and am having a hard time grasping it. The code in this makefile is very generalized I am having problem with the shortcuts

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall
DEPS = primes.h
OBJ = go.o primes.o

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

go: $(OBJ)
        gcc $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^

What does the target %.o mean ? If you wish to enter this target what will you write ?
What does its dependency mean ?
What does $@ $< mean ?
What does $@ $^ mean ?
```

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Intro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%.o` applies to all files ending in the `.o` suffix, similarly `%.c` applies to all files ending in the `.c` suffix. The `$<` is the first item in the dependencies list. The special macros `$@` and `$^`, which are the left and right sides of a rule having `:`, respectively, to make the overall compilation rule more general.

Thus,

```
go: $(OBJ)
        gcc $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

expands to:

```
gcc -Wall -o go go.o primes.o
```

And each of the object files, go.o and primes.o is checked against timestamp if they got modified.
for example,

```
%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

expands to for go.o as:
    go.o : go.c primes.h

i.e. if go.o has timestamp earlier than timestamps of either go.c or primes.h, this rule is fired.
And, the rule is:

```
gcc -Wall -c -o go.o go.c
```

`$<` expands to `go.c` (first dependency) in this case